# Issues opening a file on Android with my C#/Xamarin app

Tags: android, android-intent

```
 public void openFile ()
 {
      
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
     intent.SetType("text/plain");
     intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
     intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionOpenDocument);                  
     intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
     intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.FANCY", true);
     intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_FILESIZE", true);
     intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionOpenDocument);

     StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select file"), 0);

 }
```

What happens is that this opens up a new page listing the applicable files in Documents. I can click on a file. If the click is long, the file get a blue check mark and on the right side are four arrows and the selection has a blue background. If you rapidly double click on the arrows the file opens to the app I've selected.

How can I get my app to be the one selected? I didn't see it in the list and now I don't see how I can revisit that list.